# odoo search function on one2many relation on inline view

Tags: search, treeview, odoo

At the moment I'm a bit confused if it is not possible to search at a treeview in odoo if it is shown inline in another from view.

I have build two models which have a **many to one** / **one to many** relation.

The related content from model b is shown inside the form view from model a in an own tab as treeview. At the moment I habe the pagination, but how can I add a search field there, please see screenshot:
[treeview inside model a form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpmWr.jpg)